# Closing a modal screen in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a modal screen in my root navigator that takes up half of the screen when present. I want the user to be able to press outside the modal to close it, but is this possible? To be clear: I do not use the modal component imported from `react-native`. I am referring to a navigation screen with `{presentation: modal}`.

I tried to wrap the Navigation component in a touchable opacity, but that did not work and caused issues. I cannot find any documentation on this.